# "STR: Command not found" while assigning a value to a variable

Tags: command-line, scripts

I entered the following lines into a shell script called “test.sh”:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
STR=”Hello Again”
echo $STR
```

After chmod to executable, I ran the script with `./test.sh`. However, I get the message

```
./test.sh: line 3  STR: Command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did terdon's answer solve your question? If not it could be that you accidentally have spaces around your variable assignment.

Comment: @Voker just an stylistic comment based on [my suggestion](http://askubuntu.com/posts/795037/revisions): I think it is best to use Blockquote for error messages instead of Code block; at the end, this is not code but some text the Bash interpreter is returning.

Comment: @fedorqui why? Quote blocks don't preserve formatting, they interpret special characters (e.g. `*`,`_`, `#`) as markdown, and are rendered differently by screen reader software. I think that anything that is either given or received by a computer should be in code blocks. You never know when the exact format can be relevant. Especially when dealing with things like this where unicode comes into play.

Comment: @terdon [it really depends on cases](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165162/209901) and there is even a request to [Add format for logs/warnings/error messages which allows word-wrapping and preserves newlines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235084/209901). To me, if it is just a line like this case, I prefer quote blocks since it makes it easier to understand what is code and what is errors.

Comment: @fedorqui I guess we should take it to meta but I always prefer fixed-width font and exact format reproduction whenever posting a message that is either read or produced by a computer.

Comment: @terdon let's. I had always assumed it differently, so it is good you pinged to discuss it since obviously we see it on a different way and my previous links show that are is no consensus.

Answer (score 20):

What are you using to create that script? The quote characters you have in your question are wrong. They're not regular double quotes (`"`) but `”`. The regular quotes are:

```
$ uniprops '"' | head -1
U+0022 ‹"› \N{QUOTATION MARK}
```

While yours are:

```
$ uniprops '”' | head -1
U+201D ‹”› \N{RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}
```

So, just use regular quotes and you'll be fine:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
STR="Hello Again"
echo "$STR" ## Get into the habit of ALWAYS quoting your variables as well
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Terdon. The double quotes in the file are correct, The post was from an email.

Comment: `uniprops` looks cool. I found [the page](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle-1.111_01/script/uniprops) (is that our own tchrist?). Do I have to download it from source, or is it available in a package manager somewhere? `E: Unable to locate package uniprops`

Comment: @TRiG you need to install the `Unicode::Tussle` module. You can do that with `cpanm` if you have it (`sudo cpanm Unicode::Tussle`) or, well, just install `cpanm`, you'll thank me if you use Perl at all. And yes, that's our tchrist. He's one of *the* Perl gurus. Wrote the book and everything.

Comment: I don't use Perl much (barely at all). I just want to know more than the [minimum](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) about Unicode.

Comment: @TRiG well, in Ubuntu, it's as simple as `sudo apt-get install cpanminus; sudo cpanm Unicode::Tussle` and then you have the `uniprops` command. Of course, tchrist wrote the damn thing so you may as well ask him in chat :)

Comment: I regretfully run into this sort of nonsense all the time.  A particular wiki system at my employer seems to have a nasty habit of translating hyphen-minus `-` U+002D into hyphen `‐` U+2010 ([or similar](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html)).  Then things like `uname ‐a` stop working :-/.  Email clients often have similar nefarious habits - especially when using HTML formatting - another good reason to prefer plain-text emails.

Comment: @JaySilver hang on, do you mean that the actual file you used had correct double quotes? If so, please [edit] your question and clarify. If the quotes are correct, you most likely have a space between `STR` and `=`.